# NaN with date display in the form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the date format but when I try to display it shows the correct date with Nan-Nan-Nan and in the output box is shows Nan-Nan-Nan

This is my script

```
<script>
function dateformat(x)
{
var2 = x;    
var d1=new Date(var2);
var newdate = (d1.getDate() + "-" +( d1.getMonth()+1)+ "-" + d1.getFullYear());
document.getElementById("f_date_c_delivery_date").value = newdate;
}
</script>
```

Out is like this:

```
16-07-2013 
NaN-NaN-NaN
```

in the text box is display:

```
NaN-NaN-NaN
```

Can someone tell me what Iam doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `x` when you call `dateformat`?

Comment: this is how it is being called : onchange="dateformat(this.value)" is the date '2013-07-21'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument passed (`x`) is invalid for a date. For example :

```
var a = new Date(""); // Invalid Date

a.getDate();          // NaN
```

While in case of a valid one :

```
var a  = new Date("4/12/2012");  // Thu Apr 12 2012 ... 

a.getDate();                     // 12
```